# Find the area between two curves separately in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, line, area

I have in a list of points two different curves (y1, y2) and I want to find the area between the curves when:

- y1 > y2
- y1 < y2

I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439243/find-the-area-between-two-curves-plotted-in-matplotlib-fill-between-area), but it only calculates the sum of both areas.

If we plot what I want, I want separately the blue area and the red area.

[image: separately]

Comment: Can you show us some code of what you tried?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**:
I noticed in hindsight, that this solution is not exact and there are probably cases where it doesn't work at all. As long as there is no other better answer I will leave this here.

You can use

```
diff = y1 - y2 # calculate difference
posPart = np.maximum(diff, 0) # only keep positive part, set other values to zero
negPart = -np.minimum(diff, 0) # only keep negative part, set other values to zero
```

to seperate the blue from the red part. Then calculate their areas with `np.trapz`:

```
posArea = np.trapz(posPart)
negArea = np.trapz(negPart)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have plot it the areas and look very promising. Otherwise, the areas does not exactly match with the area of the post linked. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: I just noticed, that this solution only works as an approximation, so the values are not exactly right.