# Evaluate integral of unknown function with data table

Tags: python, integral

I want to find the 2 bounded areas. However, i dont know the function of the blue curve but i do have a data table of it. I looked up and found out the possibility of using `scipy.integrate.simps` but i dont know how to specify that the area is bounded by the red line(either upper or lower) but not by the x-axis. [image]

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.ticker import (MultipleLocator, FormatStrFormatter,
                               AutoMinorLocator)
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from scipy import interpolate
from scipy import integrate

%matplotlib inline

file = pd.read_excel("T8.xlsx","Phthalansäureanhydrid",usecols=[2,3])
X = file['Zeit(s)']
Y = file['Temperatur(Celcius Grad)']

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(X,Y,'-',color='#10A5F3', label="Phthalansäureanhydrid")
ax.grid(True, which='major', axis='both', color='#F19211', linestyle='-')
#ax.grid(True, which='minor', axis='both', color='#F19211', linestyle='--')
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
#ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
#ax.legend(loc='upper center', frameon=True)

#major & minor ticks
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(MultipleLocator(100))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%d'))
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(MultipleLocator(10))

#extrapolation - first line
temp1 = []
time1 = []
xnew1 = []
for i in file.index:
    if i > 630:
        temp1.append(file['Temperatur(Celcius Grad)'][i])
        time1.append(file['Zeit(s)'][i])
    else:
        xnew1.append(file['Zeit(s)'][i])

extrapo1 = InterpolatedUnivariateSpline(time1, temp1, k=1)
ynew1 = extrapo1(xnew1)

#extrapolation - second line
temp2 = []
time2 = []
xnew2 = []
for i in file.index:
    if 100<i<400:
        temp2.append(file['Temperatur(Celcius Grad)'][i])
        time2.append(file['Zeit(s)'][i])
    if i>400:
        xnew2.append(file['Zeit(s)'][i])

ynew2 = np.polyval(z,xnew2)
z = np.polyfit(time2,temp2,1)

#horizontal line
def hori(x):
    a = xnew1.index(x)
    b = xnew2.index(x)
    return np.linspace(ynew2[b],ynew1[a])

#integral

plt.plot(xnew1,ynew1,'-',color='black')
plt.plot(xnew2,ynew2,'-',color='black')
plt.plot([470]*len(hori(470)),hori(470),'--',color='red')

plt.savefig('phth.pdf')
```

Link to data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xznXj-aA-Szq2s4KWb-qPWYxZbQNrA5FgUCQT6i7oVo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: The area between two functions is just (integral of upper bound) - (integral of lower bound). This seems to be really a math question and not a Python question.

Comment: True! But i dont know the function of the blue line. Tho i can approximate it with polynomial functions and then i can implement what you suggest. Thanks for the idea

Comment: You can use [`numpy.trapz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) to get the area under under a line defined by a dataset. If you know the function of the red line you can apply it to the x-values of your blue line dataset to turn it into a dataset that you can integrate under too. Post some data (a working example) and we can show you how.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find the area between two curves plotted in matplotlib (fill\_between area)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439243/find-the-area-between-two-curves-plotted-in-matplotlib-fill-between-area)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll code up a basic illustrative example so you can see how you might go about something like this. This is not for your data, but should help you along:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Here are my curves
x = np.linspace(0, np.pi/2, num=100)
blue = np.sin(x)
orange = np.linspace(0.5, 0.8, num=100)
green = np.linspace(0.1, 0.2, num=100)

# Here is a plot to illustrate my example
plt.plot(x, blue, x, orange, x, green)
plt.show()
```

This plot has been annotated with the area that I want to work out; the area under the Blue curve but bounded by the Green and Orange curves:
[image: Area of interest]

So to work out this area we're going to work out the areas:

- Under the Blue curve when it's above Green and below Orange

  and add it to the area
- Under the Orange curve when it's below Blue

  then subtract the area
- Under the Green curve when it's below Blue

That's a little complex but try to picture those areas so that you can work out why we're adding and subtracting those areas. We can work out those areas using the [`np.trapz`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.trapz.html) function and by masking only the areas that we want:

```py
mask = (blue > green) * (blue < orange)
first_bullet_area = np.trapz(blue[mask], x[mask])
mask = (orange < blue)
second_bullet_area = np.trapz(orange[mask], x[mask])
mask = (green < blue)
third_bullet_area = np.trapz(green[mask], x[mask])
```

Then we just need to do that addition and subtraction:

```py
>>> first_bullet_area + second_bullet_area - third_bullet_area
0.6190953349008973
```