# Finding the largest area under a curve | pandas, matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, area

I am struggling a bit in this one - in order to find the necessary battery capacity I need to analyze production/demand over a year's worth of data. To do this, I figured I need to calculate the biggest area under the 0 line. I guess I need to find the start/end points of that area and multiply everything by its respective y-value?

Here is a shortened version of the graph I have:
[image]
That is the biggest area under the 0 in the image, but in the full dataset it could be any area. I know how to integrate it in the case I find the boundaries of the area in question but I'm struggling to find an efficient way to do that.

My dataframe looks like this:

```
                     demand  Production    diff
Time
2019-01-01 00:15:01   17.25      32.907  15.657
2019-01-01 00:30:01   17.80      32.954  15.154
...                     ...         ...     ...
2019-01-16 22:15:02   17.34      27.704  10.364
2019-01-16 22:30:01   18.67      35.494  16.824
```

I use this snippet to find the length in timesteps of the longest area but I'm missing if there's a way to multiply the points by their y-values (diff). It's **technically not correct**, however, considering that an area might be long but narrow and another might be shorter and taller, so with an overall bigger area.

```
def max0(sr):
     return (sr >= 0).cumsum().value_counts().max() - (0 if (sr >= 0).cumsum().value_counts().idxmax() < 0 else 1)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find the area between two curves plotted in matplotlib (fill\_between area)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25439243/find-the-area-between-two-curves-plotted-in-matplotlib-fill-between-area)

Comment: Not fully, no :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the largest area under the 0-line.
I generated my own data

```
x = np.random.randn(100000)
x = x.cumsum()-x.mean()
plt.plot(x);
```

[image: Sample data]

Now calculate the start and end points for positive and negative sequences. Every value in a sequence gets an increasing integer to be able to group by sequence.

```
x1 = np.diff(x < 0).cumsum()
```

Use pandas groupby to compute all areas and find the largest negative

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'value': x[1:],
    'border': x1
})
dfg = df.groupby('border')
mingr = dfg.apply(lambda x: np.trapz(x.value)).idxmin()
plt.plot(x[1:])
plt.plot(
    dfg.get_group(mingr).value
);
plt.title(
    "position from {} to {}".format(
        dfg.get_group(mingr).index[0],
        dfg.get_group(mingr).index[-1]));
```

[image: Largest Area under 0-line]

### How this works

I create a dataset that is easier to follow along

```
x = np.array([3,4,4.5,3,2])
X = np.r_[x,-x,x,-x]+np.random.normal(0,.2,20)
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.axhline(0, color='gray')
plt.plot(X, 'o--');
```

[image: Dataset]

I want to know the sequences with consecutive negative or positive values. This can be archived with the filter X < 0.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value': X, 'lt_zero': X < 0})
df[:10]
      value  lt_zero
0  3.125986    False
1  3.885588    False
2  4.580410    False
3  2.998920    False
4  1.913088    False
5 -2.902447     True
6 -3.986654     True
7 -4.373026     True
8 -2.878661     True
9 -1.929964     True
```

Now I can find the indices where the sign changes, when I diff every consecutive value. I concat one False before the data to not loose the first value.

```
df['sign_switch'] = np.diff(np.r_[False, X < 0])
df[:10]
      value  lt_zero  sign_switch
0  3.125986    False        False
1  3.885588    False        False
2  4.580410    False        False
3  2.998920    False        False
4  1.913088    False        False
5 -2.902447     True         True
6 -3.986654     True        False
7 -4.373026     True        False
8 -2.878661     True        False
9 -1.929964     True        False
```

With `cumsum()` I get for every sequence an increasing integer value. Now I have a grouping variable for every sequence.

```
df['sign_sequence'] = np.diff(np.r_[False, X < 0]).cumsum()
df[:10]
      value  lt_zero  sign_switch  sign_sequence
0  3.125986    False        False              0
1  3.885588    False        False              0
2  4.580410    False        False              0
3  2.998920    False        False              0
4  1.913088    False        False              0
5 -2.902447     True         True              1
6 -3.986654     True        False              1
7 -4.373026     True        False              1
8 -2.878661     True        False              1
9 -1.929964     True        False              1
```

For every group I can compute the integral for the values in the group.

```
sign_groups = df.groupby('sign_sequence')
sign_groups.apply(lambda x: np.trapz(x.value))
sign_sequence
0    13.984455
1   -13.654547
2    14.370044
3   -14.549090
```

You can access every group later and use the areas. For example to plot the areas.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(12,5))
plt.plot(X,'o--')
plt.axhline(0, c='gray')
for e,group in enumerate(sign_groups):
    plt.fill_between(group[1].index,0, group[1].value)
    area = np.trapz(group[1].value)
    plt.text((e)*5+1.5, np.sign(area) * 1.25, f'{area:.2f}', fontsize=12)
```

[image: Plot with Areas]

Comment: So this gets the biggest (height included) area under the curve or the longest one (just x-coordinate)? I see that you group by longitude under the 0 line, calculate the area with np.trapz(), then you apply the lambda function to find the highest negative area in the data. Okay until here. Printing mingr in my case returns a 1. Somehow this with dfg.get_group(mingr).value does... work? Getting the group for which the area is minimum, I presume? I'd be thankful if you elaborated a bit more on the step-by-step mechanics of this, if you could. :)

Comment: Also, is it possible to get the max area into a variable so I can perform further computation on it?

Comment: @eddieevt: I added an example with simpler data. And an example how to use the computed areas (here in a plot). I hope it's clear how to get the area in a variable. For max and min area you can use ```np.min()``` or ```np.max()```.

Comment: Thank you very much, you are a treasure! :)